# Angular radio input not updating model with bootstrap 4 btn-group

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have a form in angular (v2.4.8) which uses ngFor in a radio selection based on the example in [scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2). This doesn't work in my application, if I click on a radio the `user.category` does not get updated.

Code for compoonent:

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  public user: User;

  public userTypes = [
    {value: 'type1', display: 'Type 1'},
    {value: 'type2', display: 'Type 2'},
    {value: 'type3', display: 'Type 3'}
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      category: this.userTypes[0].value
    }
  }

  public save(isValid: boolean, f: User) {
    console.log(f);
  }

}
```

And the template:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label *ngFor="let userType of userTypes" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="category" [(ngModel)]="user.category" [value]="userType.value"> {{userType.display}}
  </label>
</div>
```

The user interface is as follows:

```
export interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  category: string;
}
```

**Edit**

This appears to be an issue with using bootstrap `btn-group` with angular, looks like the click event i handled correctly. I fixed it by adding a click event to the label. Answer below.

Comment: are you getting any errors? also any particular reason for doing `*ngFor` on a `label`?

Comment: your code if works fine to me, just verify that you imprted FormsModule in your module.

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine the issues seems to be with bootstrap rather than angular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with bootstrap btn-group radios rather than angular. Workaround is to add a click event to the label.

HTML:

```
<label *ngFor="let userType of userTypes" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="changeCategory(userType.value)">
  <input type="radio" name="category" [(ngModel)]="user.category" [value]="userType.value"> {{userType.display}} 
</label>
```

Javascript - added to component:

```
public changeCategory(category) {
  this.user.category = category;
}
```